# Using Dynamic MySQL to create a new table

Tags: mysql, dynamic

I want to change this query:

```
CREATE TABLE diablo.diablo_sales2 LIKE diablo.diablo_sales;
```

to a dynamic one like this:

```
set @old = 'diablo_sales';
set @new = 'diablo_sales2 ';
set @schema = 'diablo';

set @query = 'create table @schema.@new like @schema.@old';
```

Is this even possible in MySQL? How can I execute @query?

EDIT: below is the whole query I'm trying to make dynamic

```
 -- create same table structure - blank table
CREATE TABLE diablo.diablo_sales2 LIKE diablo.diablo_sales;

-- add the new column(s)
ALTER TABLE diablo.diablo_sales2 
add column new_column decimal(10);


-- insert the old data into new table - new column will remain blank
INSERT INTO diablo.diablo_sales2 
(
column1,
column2

)
SELECT * FROM diablo.diablo_sales;

-- rename the new table to its original name. Drop the old table.
RENAME table diablo_sales TO `old`, diablo_sales2 TO diablo_sales;
DROP TABLE old;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html):

```
SET @sql := CONCAT('
  CREATE TABLE `',REPLACE(@schema,'`','``'),'`.`',REPLACE(@new,'`','``'),'`
          LIKE `',REPLACE(@schema,'`','``'),'`.`',REPLACE(@old,'`','``'),'`
');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I have taken the liberty of quoting the identifiers and calling [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) to escape any quotes contained therein, in order to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: set @query = concat('create table ',@schema,'.',@new,' like ',@schema,'.', @old);

prepare query1 from @query;
execute query1;

This seems to work for me, but is your method better?

Comment: @Lucas: As explained in my post, my method protects against SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks eggyal. If I'm just running queries to manipulate data sets on my localhost, do I need to worry about potential SQL injection attacks?

Comment: If you're just running queries to manipulate data sets on your localhost, why can't you just type the `CREATE TABLE` statement directly with the intended values?

Comment: I've got a snippet I made for adding columns to large (100m rows) data sets. Rather than doing an alter table add column I duplicate the table structure, add the column, insert the old data into the new table, then drop the old table and rename the new one. (I'll show you my code in the original post). Since it references tables about 8 timees, I thought I'd try to use some Dynamic MySQL to set the table names at the top instead of repeating them all the way down. Does this make sense?

Comment: The second half of what you're looking for is stored proceedures. You can use stored proceedures to create MySql 'functions'. More information is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html. With the stored proceedures, you will be able to reuse this snippet.

Comment: @Lucas: Why do you do it that way instead of `ALTER TABLE`, which essentially does exactly that behind the scenes?

Comment: For a 100 million row table. Adding a column takes around 2 hours but the 'long way' takes around 10-15 minutes. It's a much more efficient query for some reason.